# SQL Server 2008 webservice, deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services

I am freelancing to a game server company and this game server uses a dedicated server with SQL Server 2008 on it, the game client connect to the game server on a random port (not a problem) and the SQL Server is closed down on the dedicated server, so it can't be accessed from a external source.

I am working on an idea to sell to my manager to create a web service, so I could make an online registration form and control panel to people to manage their goods online (without the game).

**Well the question is:** what's the best way to make a web service (the port 80 is open and with iis7/windows server 2008) to work on SQL Server 2008 Express, providing XML with some info to my Control Panel, and to make the online form to send a request to create new players on SQL Server too and answer with a XML confirming it?

I know I could do on PHP (since this IIS7 has php installed on it), but that would be a hell of work, and if there is no other way I will be doing it manually on php.

I would like to know if there is some way to work with something like NuSoap to work with SQL Server or any other way that is not the NATIVE SQL Server, (that I just read on microsoft website that is deprecated). *And how to do it if possible*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an [OData](http://www.odata.org/) service using WCF over an EF model of your game database. Read here: [Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx)